# database is not defined at snapshot.forEach for cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am running a cloud function every minute to delete old posts as such

```js
exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((change,context) => {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const getPostsForDate = admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('timeOfDeletion', '<', currentTime)
    return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {}
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var key = doc.id
            console.log(key)
            const convos =  database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                 if (snapshot.exists){
                    for (var child in snapshot) {
                        const convoID = child
                        console.log(child+"shit")
                        updates["conversations/" + value] = null
                    }
                 }
             })
             updates["/convoID/"+ key] = null
             updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
             updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
             const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
             const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
             batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
             batch.delete(posterRef)
        })
        return admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()
})
})
```

Essentially, the function queries firestore for posts that have a timestamp less than the current time. However, there seems to be a problem when the code iterates over each post to find the related conversations, specifically :

```js
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var key = doc.id
        console.log(key)
        const convos =  database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
```

In the console, I am getting the error:`database is not defined at snapshot.forEach` Originally, I had the code as `admin.database().ref()` but I was still getting an error that 'value' was not defined. Is it not possible to create a reference for every post like this? Is the syntax incorrect?

Edited code to include admin:

```js
exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((change,context) => {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const getPostsForDate = admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('timeOfDeletion', '<', currentTime)
    return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {}
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var key = doc.id
            console.log(key)
            const convos =  admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                 if (snapshot.exists){
                    for (var child in snapshot) {
                        const convoID = child
                        console.log(child+"shit")
                        updates["conversations/" + value] = null
                    }
                 }
             })
             updates["/convoID/"+ key] = null
             updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
             updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
             const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
             const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
             batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
             batch.delete(posterRef)
        })
        return admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()
})
})
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: value is not defined
at admin.database.ref.once (/user_code/index.js:262:52)
at onceCallback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4843:51)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4465:22
at exceptionGuard (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:691:9)
at EventList.raise (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9727:17)
at EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9681:41)
at EventQueue.raiseEventsForChangedPath (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9665:14)
at Repo.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12891:30)
at Reference.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13992:19)
at getPostsForDate.get.then.snapshot (/user_code/index.js:274:39)
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad part of it is for firebase while part of it is for firestore. The original query gets the data from the firestore while later on more information is retrieved from firebase.

Comment: It looks like that should be `admin.database().ref()...`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have already tried that and I get the error `value is not defined
    at admin.database.ref.once (/user_code/index.js:262:52)`

Comment: Please make sure your code is a [completely minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In what you shared, the `admin` call is still missing. If you get an error message, share the full and exact error message in your question too

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I included the error and updated code

Comment: The error comes from `updates["conversations/" + value] = null`, where you use a variable `value` that you didn't define anywhere. What do you expect `value` to be here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That seems to fix the problem, I wanted it to be the convoID. Am I correctly getting the key, however, when I set convoID = child? Essentially, I am iterating over each child in the snapshot and want to get the key... should I change it to child.key?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Or something like `if (snapshot.exists){
                     const convos = snapshot.val()
                    for (var child in convos) {
                        const convoID = child
                        updates["conversations/" + convoID] = null
                    }`

Comment: I wrote an answer below. But it's hard to say if this is the answer, since you're mixing a lot of technologies (Cloud Functions, Firestore, Realtime Database). Consider [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if my answer doesn't solve your problem or for any other problems. The fewer technologies you need in your question, the more likely it is that someone will spot the problem.

Comment: @Frank you solved the original question I asked ; in addition, the proposed solution also seems like it will work

Comment: Good to hear Raim. For future questions please create an MCVE. Here it took a lot of back and forth to get to a fairly straightforward (and valid) question about the realtime database. If you isolate the problem, somebody is likely to be able to help faster (and thus more people will get help).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, should I have just included part of the cloud function, then, with all the error output? (That way there would be None of the firestore stuff or the trigger)

Comment: The snippet I show in my answer is apparently all that you needed help with. So you should make a minimal version of that snippet work. Before asking a question, you should typically reproduce the problem in isolation. Nothing about my answer is related to Firestore or Cloud Functions, so you should be able to reproduce your problem with just a JavaScript snippet using the realtime database (I frequently use a site like jsbin for that). The link on [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) contains a lot more on how to do this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I’ll consider all of these when posting my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the child key, use `Snapshot.key`. You'll also want to use `Snapshot.forEach` to loop over child nodes of `/convoId/$key`.

So something like:

```
const convos =  admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        updates["conversations/" + child.key] = null
    }
 })
```